# sending emails using sendgrid nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, sendgrid-api-v3, bcc

i create this nodejs app to send emails for marcketing using sendgrid Api, in fact it's working but i have a problem that i have to remove param message `to: 'exemple@gmail.com'` and not display it in the email just the bcc recipients, this is the code:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail')
const fs = require("fs");

sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY)

const msg = {

  to: 'exemple@gmail.com',
  from: 'exemple1@gmail.com',
  bcc: ['exemple2@gmail.com','exemple3@gmail.com','exemple4@gmail.com'],
  subject: 'Sending Emails Using Sendgrid',
  html: '<p>Sending Emails Using Sendgrid</p><br><img src="cid:logo" alt="image" />',
  attachments: [{
    filename: 'img',
    type: 'image/png',
    content_id: 'logo',
    content: fs.readFileSync('imgs/img.png', { encoding: 'base64' }),
    disposition: 'inline',
  }],
};

sgMail.send(msg).then(() => {
    console.log('Email sent')
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/main/docs/use-cases/single-email-multiple-recipients.md), you should be using the `sendMultiple` method instead of the `send` method.